# i am trying to use RadList for the first time, but i just get a blank screen. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: angular, nativescript

i am trying to use RadList for the first time, but i just get a blank screen. What am i doing wrong?
i even tried put 'example' string in the label, but got the same result

"cats" is a list with objects with 'id' property.

i installed the nativescript-ui-listview plugin

```
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <RadListView [items]="cats">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label [text]="item.id"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

i don't get any error, just white screen

Comment: Please share the complete code including the controller or possibly a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

are you importing NativeScriptUIListViewModule into your module?